# PHP7/PHPWord. Как спарсить тэги table и создать .docx файл с таблицей?

Tags: php, ms-word, table, docx, phpword

Есть строка вида:

```
"обычный текст </table>строка1;строка2;
строка3;<table/><03> обычный текст \n
обычный текст </table>строка1;строка2;
строка3;<table/><03> обычный текст"
```

P.S. `;` - разделяет содержимое строк `<03>` - это кол-во столбцов

Вопросы:

1. Как спарсить текст между тегами `table`, если вместе с ними на одной строке может быть и обычный текст до них и после них, а также могут иметься разрывы строк вида `\n` ????
2. Как создать документ .docx и Вставить в него таблицу с этим текстом между тегами `table` используя PHPWord??